# Android SQLite get maximum value with respect to other columns

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table called 'tracked_exercises' which contains columns shown in the attached picture (exercise_name, band, reps, kgs)

I'd like to create a query which given an exercise_name returns all rows which have any of these conditions for that exercise_name

- Max reps with each unique band
- Max kgs at each reps with matching band(But not if max kgs are lower or equal than max kgs with higher reps. So if you have 2 reps with 6kg, and 3 reps with 6kg I do not want the 2 reps with 6kg back)

So in the example image if I give 'Muscle Up' I would get back

```
   | band   | reps | kgs |
   | red    | 10   | 0   |
   | purple | 15   | 0   |
   | No     | 5    | 0   |
   | No     | 4    | 10  |
   | No     | 2    | 15  |
```

I have been able to get the maximum reps for each unique band with the below query, but haven't managed to work out how to get rows with max kgs as well

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM tracked_exercises INNER JOIN (SELECT band, MAX(reps) AS Maxreps FROM tracked_exercises WHERE exercise_name =:name GROUP BY band ) topset ON tracked_exercises.band = topset.band AND tracked_exercises.reps = topset.Maxreps")
List<TrackedExercise> getPersonalRecords(String name);
```

Sorry if this is not clear, comment if you need more info

[Example tracked_exercises table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUP2e.png)

Another example:

```
| band  | reps | kgs |
| No    | 3    | 2.5 |
| No    | 3    | 5   |
| No    | 3    | 6.25|
| No    | 10   | 0   |
| No    | 9    | 0   |
| No    | 4    | 5   |
| No    | 4    | 3.75|
| red   | 11   | 0   |
| red   | 10   | 0   |
| No    | 2    | 6.25|
```

I'd like the result:

```
| band  | reps | kgs |
| No    | 10   | 0   |
| red   | 11   | 0   |
| No    | 3    | 6.25|
| No    | 4    | 5   |
```

Edit: updated question to make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `CTE` to get all the maximums for `reps` and `kgs` and then `NOT EXISTS` on the results:

```
with cte as (
  select t.band, t.reps, t.kgs
  from ( 
    select *,
      row_number() over (partition by band order by reps desc) rnreps,
      row_number() over (partition by band, reps order by kgs desc) rnkgs
    from tracked_exercises
  ) t  
  where t.rnreps = 1 or t.rnkgs = 1
)  
select c.* from cte c
where not exists (
  select 1 from cte
  where band = c.band and reps > c.reps and kgs >= c.kgs
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ekNDkvnWCgRbAPabvkcmGY/0).
Results:

```
| band | reps | kgs  |
| ---- | ---- | ---- |
| No   | 10   | 0    |
| No   | 4    | 5    |
| No   | 3    | 6.25 |
| red  | 11   | 0    |
```

Comment: I should have been more clear with my final bullet point. So if I have 2 rows which have band: No and reps: 4 but one has 3.75kg and the other 5kg. I'd like to get back just the higher(5kg) row when the band and reps match. As kgs can be decimal do you know which data type it should use, I'm guessing DOUBLE? Here's a link which demostrates the issue https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oxmu4LC3weRDmAMd5RWpZi/3

Comment: In your question you mention *Max reps* but in your comment you say that you want *Max kgs*. Edit your question and clarify and post expected results for this case too.

Comment: Sorry forpas have updated the question - hopefully more clear now!

Comment: Thanks @forpas that's great, I edited a little just to add back in the filtering for exercise name. Now I want to work out *how* it works :) You've been super helpful! https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ekNDkvnWCgRbAPabvkcmGY/1